# Consumer not picking up messages from queue

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

I have an osgi bundle which has a few camel routes. Now everything works fine for a while. After a while one of the routes stops picking up messages. Messages get sent to the queue but the route does not pick it up. I can see number of pending messages growing and one consumer on the queue but nothing happens. On a restart of the bundle things work fine again. Any ideas why this can occur ? Other routes in the bundle work fine while the route under question does not.

Comment: Are there messages dispatched (dispatch cont) to the consumer?  Or if you can view the route via JMX see if there are any "in-flight" messages.

Comment: Does the route that stops working make an HTTP call by chance?

Comment: Did you check the log to see if the JMS connection is broken?

Comment: Cant view route via JMS - got network issues there . No route sends to a JMS queue and waits for a response before doing stuff. JMS connection is fine. Have an unlimited timeout on the queue so when the queue does not return anything the thread waits on it and processes no further messages. Changing the timeout to a min or so works because it times out. But not sure why the timeoutexception is not propagated back to the caller from the Q i am sending the message to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like your route has only 1 consumer thread and its simply blocked from finishing and dequeuing more messages (until you kill/restart it)...

use a thread dump to confirm and identify of the culprit API...likely a slow process or external resource call (database, HTTP, network issue, etc)

Comment: indeed it has one consumer only .